# flask is not picking parameters supplied for post request

Tags: python, flask

I created a resource containing post method which takes user_name, client_dict, order_detail_dict as arguments/parameters as below

```css
class CreateOrder(Resource):
    def post(self, user_name, client_dict, order_detail_dict):
```

and I registered resource as below with the endpoint /create_order

```css
api_createorders_addproducts.add_resource(CreateOrder, '/create_order')
```

If I make a post request as

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/create_order?user_name={'name':'panda'}&client_dict={'clientname':'panda'}&order_detail_dict={'detail':'details}`

it still tells me that

> TypeError: post() missing 3 required positional arguments:
>   'user_name', 'client_dict', and 'order_detail_dict'

Can anybody point out the mistake, because I am passing all 3 required parameters in the post request but still it tells me that its missing. Thanks in advance

Comment: POST requests work on data that is contained in the message body, not items that are passed as params.

Comment: I think since this is a POST request, your data should do into the request body, not onto the parameter list of the URL.

Comment: I tried putting in body instead, still getting the same error using Postman

Comment: I think your parameters are in requests.args not a post arguments. for post argument you need something similar to this  api.add_resource(CreateOrder , '/create_order/<str:user_name>')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every argument that you supply in your `post` definition, you must also pass in a value for it like so:

```py
def post(self, user_name, client_dict, order_detail_dict):
    pass
```

You need a url with all these parameters:

`/create_order/<username>/<client_dict>/<order_detail_dict>`

Or it will not work.

A way around this (since you may not want to define these with every URL) is to supply defaults in case they are missing and convert them into keyword arguments like this:

```py
def post(self, user_name=None, client_dict=None, order_detail_dict=None):
    pass
```

Then you do not need them at all and they become optional parts of the URL.

> The arguments in your view function are mapped to arguments in your URL

However, based on your question, you are trying to POST some data. That data should not be in your URL string at all. Instead try this:

```py
class CreateOrder(Resource):
    def post(self):
        json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        print(json_data)
```

and then your post request would look like this:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"name":"panda","client_dict": {"clientname": "panda"}, "order_detail_dict": {"detail": "details"}}' \
  http://127.0.0.1:5000/create_order
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parameters from the post function, use request.get_json and restructure your input on postman

```
class CreateOrder(Resource):
    def post(self):
        json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        user_name = json_data['name']
        client_dict= json_data['client_dict']
        order_detail_dict= json_data['order_detail_dict']
        return jsonify(order_detail_dict)
```

Change postman body raw to:

```
{
   "name":"panda",
   "client_dict":{"clientname":"panda"},
   "order_detail_dict":{"details":"detail"}
}
```